# homomorphisms on $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Is it true that a group homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ that is injective must be an isomorphism?

I know that non zero homomorphisms $g:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ are all injective but are isomorphisms only if $g(1)=\pm 1$. But the situation for homomorphisms of
$f:\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ is not clear to me.. I know that $f $ is completely determined by $f(1,0)$ and  $f(0,1)$

Comment: if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two copies of $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ and $f:G_1\to G_2$ injective and we know that there exists $h:G_2\to G_1$ surjective (does this imply that $f$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: Since a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^k$ is necessarily isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{\ell}$ for some $\ell$, $0\leq \ell\leq k$, the image of any homomorphism $f\colon\mathbb{Z}^m\to\mathbb{Z}^n$ is necessarily isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^r$ for some $r$, $0\leq r\leq \min(m,n)$. Since the map $\mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{Z}^n$ given by $(a,b)\mapsto (ka,kb)$, $k\neq 0$, is one-to-one but not onto for $|k|\gt 1$, no such map is necessarily onto.

Comment: Of course not. $h$ always exists (take the identity); you are placing absolutely no restrictions on $f$ by positing the existence of $h$. Now, if $h$ is a *retraction* (i.e., $h\circ f = \mathrm{id}_{G_1}$), then that means that $G_2\cong \mathrm{Im}(f)\oplus\mathrm{ker}(h)$, and *that* will mean that $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin : This is exactly the situation i'm in: $f$ having a retraction. i can see by using the iso theorem that $G_2\cong Im(f)\oplus ker(h)$ but why does this imply that $f$ is an iso?

Comment: Perhaps you should have *added* all hypotheses, instead of omitting them? Please add the hypothesis to the question, but as an `Addition` so that it does not invalidate previous answers.

Comment: you are absolutely right but i thought it was a property of homomorphisms on $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ but now i see that it is a general fact for homomorphisms with retraction.

Comment: Since the question does not reflect the accepted answer, and you have failed to include all relevant information into the question, I am downvoting the question as not a good question. If you edit the question to include all relevant information, I will remove the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, it seems that the actual situation is:

> Suppose that $f,h\colon\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ are group homomorphisms, and that $h$ is a retraction of $f$; that is, $h\circ f = \mathrm{id}$. Is $f$ an isomorphism?

The answer in that situation is "yes".

Since $h\circ f$ is bijective, $f$ is one-to-one and $h$ is onto. It is also straightforward to verify that 
$$\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathrm{Im}(f) \oplus \mathrm{ker}(h).$$
Both $\mathrm{Im}(f)$ and $\mathrm{ker}(h)$ are free abelian. Since $f$ is one-to-one, $\mathrm{Im}(f)$ is free abelian of rank $2$. Since the rank of a free abelian group is uniquely determined, this means that
$$2 = \mathrm{rank}(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}) = \mathrm{rank}(\mathrm{Im}(f))+\mathrm{rank}(\mathrm{ker}(h)) = 2 + \mathrm{ker}(h),$$
so $\mathrm{ker}(h)$ is trivial. Therefore, $h$ is one-to-one and onto, hence bijective, and since $h\circ f = \mathrm{id}$, it follows that $f$ is the inverse of $h$, and an isomorphism.

Answer (score 10):

A more interesting exercise is what condition on $f(1,0) = (a,b)$ and $f(0,1) = (c,d)$  is needed for the homomorphism $f: {\mathbb Z} \oplus {\mathbb Z} \to {\mathbb Z} \oplus {\mathbb Z}$ to be an isomorphism?  The answer is that $ad - bc = \pm 1$ is necessary and sufficient.  Now generalize to homomorphisms of ${\mathbb Z}^n$ to itself.

Comment: Kind Sir, could you please elaborate on $ad - bc = \pm 1$ being necessary and sufficient. How could I go about proving that? I see that if it is nonzero then it is injective. Thank you

Comment: $f(x,y) = x (a,b) + y (c,d) = (x,y) \pmatrix{a & b\cr c & d}$.  $f$ is an isomorphism iff the matrix $\pmatrix{a & b\cr c & d\cr}$  has an inverse with integer entries, and that is true iff the determinant is $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 5):

I believe $f(a,b)=(2a,2b)$ is an easy counterexample.

It is easy to see that this map is injective group homomorphism, but it is not surjective.

---

As [Arturo Magidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/742/arturo-magidin) pointed out in his comment, for any injective homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ the image $\operatorname{Im} f$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$, i.e., it is a free Abelian group of rank 2. Even more, for any homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ the image is generated by $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$, which implies that it will be a free Abelian group. (It is explained more detailed in the comments.)

Comment: Of course, the observation is a bit silly stated that way: any injective group homomophism gives an isomorphism onto its image. What I was thinking is "the image of *any* morphism must be trivial, cyclic, or free abelian of rank $2$".

Comment: @Arturo Sorry, it seems that I misunderstood your comments. Hopefully added text together with your comments clarifies the situation.)

Comment: You didn't misunderstand them: I expressed myself poorly (then deleted and rephrased). So no worries.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Robert Israel's answer, consider the $n$-fold direct sum $R^{n}$ where $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$. A homomorphism $f:R^{n} \rightarrow R^{n}$ corresponds to an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ with entries in $R$. It turns out that $f$ is injective if and only if $\det (M)$ is a regular element (i.e., non zero divisor) in $R$ and an isomorphism if and only if $\det (M)$ is a unit of $R$, whence Robert's condition. So, every injective $f$ is an isomorphism if (and only if) every regular element of $R$ is a unit. Such are rings are often called "quorings."